# Trying to display an image in a Android mobile app using worklight

Tags: android, html, ibm-mobilefirst, imagesource

I'm building an android application using the worklight platform and am pretty new to html and javascript.  I'm trying to display an image in the top row of a table in the app using the following html code:

```
 <tr>
        <td colspan="100"><img src="/appName/apps/appName/common/images/image.jpg" alt="app image" width="250" height="75"></td>

</tr>
```

I run the app as android>>Build all and deploy.  Then using the browser simulator to view it.  For whatever reason the image displays just fine in the IDE but doesn't display at all in the browser simulator.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Is my image stored in an ok location?  Do I need to add any type of path to the css file?
Any help would be great!!

note: I also tried storing the image in the android>>images directory and had the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific question, the `src` path should point to "images\image.jpg".

That said, I do suggest learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript **outside** the scope of Worklight, because it **is** expected that you'll understand these web technologies to some degree...

As for learning Worklight-specifics, you should consult with the [IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Idan.  I'm in the process of learning it all, so I've just been playing around with it.  You're answer worked!